# How to make a button in Java fx open a new window

Tags: javafx

[Pop up instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNozm.png)I am unsure of how to have a button open a new window in java fx. So if I was creating a game, would I create a new stage for the popup window? I attached a photo.

This is my code for my button, I already added it to the scene.

```
Button in = new Button("  Instructions");
    in.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
            event.consume();

            }

        });
```

Comment: you want a whole window or just a pop up small window where you click on Ok?

Comment: You can think of a JavaFX `Stage` as a "window." So you'll want to have your button create a new `Stage` and then show it.

Comment: What is the problem with your code, though? If you are creating the alert, you just need to call `alert.show()` and a new window/popup will display for you.

Comment: Overlooked alert.show, thanks